# How to get around appengine/aetest context crashing from Infof/Warningf calls

Tags: google-app-engine, go

In my code I want to be able to log so I have passed the appengine context around my libraries. Then if there is a failure I can log to appengine like so:

context.Warningf("This is not correct!")

I am trying to write a unit test to specifically hit an error case. I am using the appengine/aetest package like this:

context, createErr := aetest.NewContext(nil)

When the test hits the above context.Warningf it fails because aetest.Context does not implement that function.

Is there a recommended way around this? For example, I guess I could set some variable to be "liv", "test" and then not log if in test but that seems hacky. Or is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: can you post a snippet of your test code  ?

Comment: Nevermind. I am an idiot. This is because LiteIDE uses go binary and not the goapp binary. It looks like everything runs fine when I use goapp test...

Answer (score 0):

This was not a real problem, it was simply an incorrect environment. It was caused by me running tests in LiteIDE without setting up correctly.